# How to change SQLITE_MAX_COLUMN in Python?

Tags: python, sqlite

all:

I'm a Python user,not familiar with SQLite.
I try to write **a dataframe with 3892 columns into SQLite table** using the `dataframe.to_sql()` method.
And Python told me there is an OperationalError:
[image]

After google, I found that the Python embedded SQLite has a **default Maximum Number Of Columns of 2000** in one table.([Limits In SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html)) The page said:

```
The default setting for SQLITE_MAX_COLUMN is 2000. You can change it at compile time to values as large as 32767.
```

My question is that: my SQLite version is already complied and embedded in Python, how can I change the default setting of max columns of SQLite in Python?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change this value without recompiling SQLite.

Having a large number of columns is generally bad form in relational database design. Assuming that having that many columns makes sense for your data, you should consider using a different tool than SQLite, as even the documentation you link to mentions that SQLite has numerous algorithms that provide quadratic performance (O(N<sup>2</sup>) for N columns).

Comment: My data column is the "Stocks Symbol", and the index is datetime. You see that the index number is even larger! So, I might consider another SQL. Or just split the "Stocks Symbol" column into several mini-columns which refer to different markets. Thank you for reply!

Comment: You're welcome. A relational schema that may work for you is to have three columns: StockSymbol, Date, Price.