# R- too many columns when using sqldf to join dataframes

Tags: r

I'm trying to merge two data frames into one. The first df is `acutedm11` with 4682 columns and the second is `gwlfullflattened22` with 4903 columns. I can't post the data here because its too big and it contains sensitive information. I'm trying to merge these two dfs based off of mrn=mrn_G and date difference <= 30

Code:

```
library(sqldf)
acutedm3 <- sqldf::sqldf("
    select acutedm11.*, gwlfullflattened22.*
    from acutedm11
       left join gwlfullflattened22 on acutedm11.mrn = gwlfullflattened22.mrn_G
        and gwlfullflattened22.EncounterDate_G between acutedm11.Date_m30 and acutedm11.Date_p30") %>%
  select(-Date_m30, -Date_p30)
```

Error: `Error: too many columns on acutedm11`

Is there a better way to merge/join the data frames?

Answer (score 1):

1. The maximum number of columns is a compile time parameter in SQLite (which is included in the RSQLite package).  You can reset the limit higher and rebuild that package.   For more info see: [Maximum number of columns in a table for sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63360925/maximum-number-of-columns-in-a-table-for-sqlite)
2. Also sqldf supports 4 different back end: [SQLite](https://www.dbtalks.com/tutorials/learn-sqlite/what-are-the-limitations-of-sqlite), [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#limits_limitations), [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html#:%7E:text=The%20internal%20representation%20of%20a,the%20rest%20of%20the%20row.) and [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/limits.html).  Try one of the others.

For example, using H2 this does not give me any errors.

```
library(RH2)
library(sqldf)

nr1 <- 100
nc1 <- 4682 
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(seq_len(nr1*nc1), nr1))

nr2 <- 100
nc2 <- 4903
df2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(seq_len(nr2*nc2), nr2))

res <- sqldf("select * from df1 a
       left join df2 b on a.V1 = b.V1
        and a.V2 between b.V3 and b.V4")
```

Comment: I'm using RStudio. I looked at the guide you sent me but there aren't any instructions on how to increase the maximum number of columns in R.

Comment: I increased the max columns in R by typing `DSQLITE_MAX_COLUMN=1234567` and `RSQLITE_MAX_COLUMN=1234567` . I still got the same error. How can I use H2, MySQL, or PostgreSQL without downloading anything?

Comment: Those parameters must be changed in the C code source and then rebuild RSQLite.  To use H2 make sure java is installed and then install the RH2 package from CRAN.  Be sure to read ?sqldf .

Comment: Thank you for providing the sample code. I tried it and got the same error. `Error: too many columns on acutedm11`

Comment: If you got the same error you are likely still using SQLite and didn't load RH2.  Add the `verbose=TRUE` argument to `sqldf`  to check which database is being used.

Comment: The RH2 library doesn't load fully so I believe you're right. I'm working with my system admin to download java so the library loads. Can you pleas edit your code with how you would insert the `verbose=TRUE line`? Thanks.

Comment: The java runtime has an automated installer so it is trivial to install.  I wouldn't think you need an "administrator" for that unless your system is somehow locked down.  Use `sqldf(..., verbose=TRUE)` to get feedback on which database it is using.

Comment: When trying to use `library(RH2)`, I get the following error `> library(RH2)
Loading required package: RJDBC
Loading required package: rJava
java.home option: 
JAVA_HOME environment variable: D:\AshSajan\Java\jre7
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry
Error: package ‘rJava’ could not be loaded
In addition: Warning message:
In fun(libname, pkgname) :
  Java home setting is INVALID, it will be ignored.`

Comment: When trying `verbose = true` , I get the following error `sqldf: library(RMySQL)
sqldf: m <- dbDriver("MySQL")
Error in .local(drv, ...) : 
  Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)
Error in !dbPreExists : invalid argument type`. I made sure to remove the `MySQL` package but it still uses it and prints the same error.

Comment: Note that if you don't specify which database driver you want to use then by default it looks to see if any database driver packages that it supports are loaded and if so it uses that database.  Either specify the database as per instructions in ?sqldf or else make sure that the only database loaded is the one you want.   If you intended to use MySQL then you need to configure it properly.  There is some info in ?sqldf but MySQL is not as easy to install and configure as H2.