# Error on `rJava` when using `RH2` for `sqldf`

Tags: r

I have the sqldf code below to merge two data frames. I understand I need the `RH2` package. I pasted the error onto google to find solutions but most of the solutions listed is because of people being unable to download the `rJava` library. Do I absolutely need that library or can I run the code below without the rJava library? I'm waiting on my system admin to help me install java as I'm not allowed to. Solutions I've found [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29522088/rjava-install-error-java-home-cannot-be-determined-from-the-registry) and [2](https://www.r-statistics.com/2012/08/how-to-load-the-rjava-package-after-the-error-java_home-cannot-be-determined-from-the-registry/) . If there's alternatives I can do or use for sqldf to get the code to run, please let me know.

[CODE (w source link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69968371/r-too-many-columns-when-using-sqldf-to-join-dataframes/69968889?noredirect=1#comment123760607_69968889) :

```
library(sqldf)
library(RH2)


nr1 <- 100
nc1 <- 4682 
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(seq_len(nr1*nc1), nr1))

nr2 <- 100
nc2 <- 4903
df2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(seq_len(nr2*nc2), nr2))

options(sqldf.driver = "H2")
res <- sqldf("select * from df1 a
       left join df2 b on a.V1 = b.V1
        and a.V2 between b.V3 and b.V4")
```

ERROR:

```
Loading required package: RJDBC
Loading required package: rJava
java.home option: 
JAVA_HOME environment variable: D:\Ash\Java\jre7
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry
Error: package ‘rJava’ could not be loaded
In addition: Warning message:
In fun(libname, pkgname) :
  Java home setting is INVALID, it will be ignored.
Please do NOT set it unless you want to override system settings.
Error in !dbPreExists : invalid argument type
```

Comment: H2 is a java database and can't be run without java. There is something wrong with your java installation. Try googling for *install rjava windows*.  When copying someone else's online code please reference the link where it was copied from.  That link already provided alternatives that sqldf supports.

Comment: I will do that. Thank you for all your help. I edited my post w source link :)